# Dictionary: Append to a value of list when the key is a tuple

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

I'm trying to append values to a list where the key is a tuple. But I keep on getting keyError because dictionary in python cannot access a tuple as key.

N.B: What I'm trying to do:

1. I have a json file. I'm trying to group by n items which will be my key for the dictionary. Then I'll return a corresponding list of dictionary for the key of tuple.
2. I'm trying to do this in a function.

Find my sample code below:

```
def group_by_field(data, fields):
    if len(fields) > 1:
        groups = {fields: []}
        for parameter in data:
            for k, v in groups.items():
                for i in fields:
                    if i in k:
                        groups[parameter[k]].append(parameter)
        return groups
```

The following is an example where I try to implement the function:

```
group_by_field(scripts, ('bnf_name', 'bnf_code'))
```

where `scripts` is a json file

Here is what the json object, `scripts`, look like:

```
[{'bnf_code': '0101010G0AAABAB',
  'items': 2,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'bnf_name': 'Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F',
  'nic': 5.98,
  'act_cost': 5.56,
  'quantity': 1000},
 {'bnf_code': '0101021B0AAAHAH',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'bnf_name': 'Alginate_Raft-Forming Oral Susp S/F',
  'nic': 1.95,
  'act_cost': 1.82,
  'quantity': 500}]
```

Here is what a sample output should look like:

```
{('Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F', '0101010G0AAABAB'): [{'bnf_code': '0101010G0AAABAB',
      'items': 2,
      'practice': 'N81013',
      'bnf_name': 'Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F',
      'nic': 5.98,
      'act_cost': 5.56,
      'quantity': 1000}],
 ('Alginate_Raft-Forming Oral Susp S/F', '0101021B0AAAHAH'): [{'bnf_code': '0101021B0AAAHAH',
      'items': 1,
      'practice': 'N81013',
      'bnf_name': 'Alginate_Raft-Forming Oral Susp S/F',
      'nic': 1.95,
      'act_cost': 1.82,
      'quantity': 500}]
```

Comment: `"dictionary in python cannot access a tuple as key."` That statement is wrong, tuples **can** be (and are often) used as keys. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Given how frequently JSON is confused with the data *decoded* from JSON here, are you sure `scripts` isn't just an ordinary `dict` that *came* from a JSON file?

Comment: Could you give input example and output expected ?

Comment: @DeepSpace I've just updated the questions to show what the scripts look like.

Comment: @azro I just provided an input example of scripts

Comment: @toch_okafor Please provide also the expected output, because your code is unclear.

Comment: `scripts` is a variable; how did you set its value using the contents of the file?

Comment: @jferard I've provided an example of the expected output.

Comment: @chepner scripts is just an example sliced out of the original json file.

Comment: Then this question isn't about JSON at all; you're just working with a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you try to use the keu `('bnf_name', 'bnf_code')` to access a data in an object like the following, and this tuple key does not exist.

```
{'bnf_code': '0101010G0AAABAB', 'items': 2, 'practice': 'N81013', 'bnf_name': 'Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F', 'nic': 5.98, 'act_cost': 5.56, 'quantity': 1000}
```

---

You may not use `fields` as key, you want the corresponding values for each object to be the key, so for each key get the value, and use this as tuple as the key :

```
def build_with_keys(values, fields):
    if len(fields) > 1:
        result = {}
        for value in values:
            key = tuple(value[k] for k in fields)
            result[key] = value
        return result
```

Comment: Thanks @azro for your response. But I've the question to show what the output should look like. The key as tuple should be the corresponding value in the json dictionary. And this is where it gets very tricky for me. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: @toch_okafor this has sense now you show the output , this is not a group operation , I’ll show you

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues here:

- when you try to append something to `groups[parameter[k]]`, `k` has the value `('bnf_name', 'bnf_code')` and is obviously not in dicts of `scripts`.
- even if you solve the previous issue, `parameter[k]` won't exist in `groups`
- you are modifying the dictionary `groups` during the iteration, which is forbidden.

And a question: what do return if `len(fields) <= 1`? `None`? an empty dict? I suggest you should return an empty dict or raise an error.

Try this:

```
def group_by_field(data, fields):
    if len(fields) <= 1:
        return {}

    groups = {}
    for parameter in data:
        key = tuple(parameter[k] for k in fields)
        groups.setdefault(key, []).append(parameter)

    return groups
```

Build the key from the field `('bnf_name', 'bnf_code')`: `('Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F', '0101010G0AAABAB')`, ... using `tuple` (which is hashable). And then append the current dict to the `groups[key]` list. If this list doesn't exist yet, it is created by `setdefault`.